# I need to make a copy for clipboard taking a dynamic variable angular

Tags: angular, typescript

**HTML**

OBS: The Technical.url specification variable is dynamic, whenever I click the button I want to copy the url.

```html
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start" fxFlex="70" class="">
    <span>{{technicalSpecification.url}}</span>
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center end" fxFlex="10">
    <button mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon matTooltip="Copy Service URL""> content_copy </mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>Here is the function which I am using for the copy to clipboard</del>

**DEPRECATED** [FOR MORE INFO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

```
copyToClipboardHelper(text: string) {
  const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  textArea.value = text;

  // Avoid scrolling to bottom
  textArea.style.top = '0';
  textArea.style.left = '0';
  textArea.style.position = 'fixed';

  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.focus();
  textArea.select();
  let successful = false;
  try {
    successful = document.execCommand('copy');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Oops, unable to copy', err);
  }

  document.body.removeChild(textArea);

  return !!successful;
}
```

<del>YOUR HTML Template</del>

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start" fxFlex="70" class="">
    <span>{{technicalSpecification.url}}</span>
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center end" fxFlex="10">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="copyToClipboardHelper(technicalSpecification.url)">
        <mat-icon matTooltip="Copy Service URL""> content_copy </mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am so sorry, just noticed `document .execCommand ` is deprecated, try to use @Robert's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628019/11769164)

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center start" fxFlex="70" class="">
    <span>{{technicalSpecification.url}}</span>
</div>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center end" fxFlex="10">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="onCopy()">
        <mat-icon matTooltip="Copy Service URL""> content_copy </mat-icon>
    </button>
</div>
```

TS:

```
onCopy(): void {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.technicalSpecification.url).then(function() {
  /* clipboard successfully set */
}, function() {
  /* clipboard write failed */
});
}
```

Comment: One question: Is this supported on all of the modern browsers?

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan You can check the support on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) page

Comment: yup, I checked, but it didn't work on Safari 14.0

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan According to docs "This API is designed to supersede accessing the clipboard using document.execCommand()." also check if you use https or localhost

Comment: Actually, I tried in the console, maybe I did something wrong. Ok, will play with this and let you know. Thank you